# Setter method does not operating properly on objects?

Tags: java, object, setter

I have two classes `DotCom` class and `DotComBust` class. First one is obviously to create object and methods that can be called upon `DotCom` object. So, as assignment said, I have to create a setter method which will set name of a particular `DotCom` object.

```
package paket1;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DotCom {

    private ArrayList<String> locationCells;
    private String name;

    public void setLocationCells(ArrayList<String> loc){
        locationCells = loc;
    }

    public void setName(String n){
        name = n;
    }
```

Now, in the `DotComBust` class, I have tried to actually set those `name`s

```
package paket1;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DotComBust {


        ArrayList<DotCom> dotComsList;  
        int numOfGuesses = 0;
        GameHelper helper = new GameHelper();

        private void setUpGame(){

            DotCom one = new DotCom();
            one.setName("Pets.com");

            DotCom two = new DotCom();
            two.setName("Go2.com");

            DotCom three = new DotCom();
            three.setName("AskMe.com"); 

            dotComsList.add(one);
            dotComsList.add(two);
            dotComsList.add(three); 

            for (DotCom dotComs : dotComsList){
                ArrayList<String> newLocation = helper.placeDotCom(3); 
                dotComs.setLocationCells(newLocation);  
            }
        }
```

But for some reason I get this message, when I put cursor on `setName`[image]

I do have `setName` method defined in `DotCom` class. *What I need to do to fix this ?*

The same problem occurs when I try to iterate through `dotComsList` and try to assign each of the `dotComs` an ArrayList of Strings.

P.S. This assignment is from HeadFirst book, the whole code can be found at page 148.

Comment: `DotCom` looks like it's not saved in your workspace yet. Do you still get the error if you save all of your files?

Comment: your DotCom class is not saved in the screenshot. Just save it, it should solve your problem.